# AssertionFailedException while trying FilteredTree

Tags: java, swt, jface, viewer

im trying to use a filtered tree in my SWT application. I added all the required jar files to the build path. When I run the application in getting the following exception

```
org.eclipse.core.runtime.AssertionFailedException: null argument:
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.Assert.isNotNull(Assert.java:85)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.Assert.isNotNull(Assert.java:73)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.util.PrefUtil.getAPIPreferenceStore(PrefUtil.java:70)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.getPreferenceStore(PlatformUI.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.ui.dialogs.FilteredTree.init(FilteredTree.java:302)
    at org.eclipse.ui.dialogs.FilteredTree.<init>(FilteredTree.java:247)
    at com.sample.TreeView.createContents(TreeView.java:61)
    at com.sample.TreeView.open(TreeView.java:40)
    at com.sample.TreeView.main(TreeView.java:29)
```

Here is my code.

```
PatternFilter patternFilter = new PatternFilter();
        patternFilter.setIncludeLeadingWildcard(true);
        filteredTree = new FilteredTree(shell, SWT.BORDER | SWT.H_SCROLL | SWT.V_SCROLL, patternFilter, true);

        TreeViewer viewer = filteredTree.getViewer();
        tree = viewer.getTree();
        tree.setHeaderVisible(true);

        TreeColumn modelColumn = new TreeColumn(tree, SWT.LEFT);
        modelColumn.setText("Model");
        modelColumn.setWidth(400);

        TreeViewerColumn treeViewerModelColumn = new TreeViewerColumn(viewer, modelColumn);
        treeViewerModelColumn.setLabelProvider(new ColumnLabelProvider());
```

Answer (score 1):

You can only use `FilteredTree` in a full Eclipse RCP since it depends on numerous other Eclipse plugins and all the initialization that is done when the RCP is started.

You can't use this in a SWT application.

Comment: Is there any class in SWT/JFace which will reproduce  FilteredTree

Comment: http://eclipsesource.com/blogs/2012/10/26/filtering-tables-in-swtjface/ Please check this link. I'm trying to reproduce the same

Comment: No. FilteredTree basically uses TreeViewer with a ViewerFilter but you will have to code that yourself.

Comment: The blog is not making it very clear but it is definitely using code which only works in an RCP.